# Which datastructure do nodes of B-Trees use?

Tags: sqlite, b-tree, ext3

> According to Knuth's definition, a **B-tree of order m** (the maximum
>   number of children for each node) is a tree which satisfies the
>   following properties:
>
> (1) Every node has at most m children.
>
> (2) Every node (except root) has at least ⌈m⁄2⌉ children.
>
> (3) The root has at least two children if it is not a leaf node.
>
> (4) A non-leaf node with k children contains k−1 keys.
>
> (5) All leaves appear in the same level, and carry information.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Definition)

Some visualizations of B-Trees look like this:

[image]

From this visualization, I would think that each node has an array datastructure (or at least something similar).

Others look like this:
[image]

This looks rather as a list-like datastructure.

So my question is:

**Which datastructure do B-trees use?**

Examples for the usage in my algorithms class were databases and filesystems. Does anybody  know how [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) implements B-tree nodes? Or [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3)? Or any other (well-known) real-world example?

Comment: There are B-trees and B+-trees. The former stores values with the associated keys. The later duplicate keys and store values in leaves.

Comment: The SQLite B-tree implementaton is described in some detail in section 1.5 here: https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html

Answer (score 0):

B-Tree itself is the datastructure (also an indexstructure).
Here is an pseudocode example (without needed methods and some needed definitions, this is an good excersize!):

The Body of a node:

```
class BNode
{
    int keys[];
    BNode children[];

    public BNode() {}

    public BNode() {}

    public int getValue(int key) {}

    public BNode getChildren(int key) {}
}
```

And the body of the B-Tree:

```
class BTree
{
    BNode root;

    BTree()
    {
        root = new BNode(null);
    }

    BNode search(int key) {}

    void insert(int key) {}

    void delete(int key) {}
}
```

---

In real world:

[Here is the B-Tree implementation](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/access/nbtree/nbtree.c) of PostgreSQL which is used for indexing the database.